# How to create a new Meteor project in an existing directory?

Tags: meteor

There is already a git repository in the directory. I see only

```
meteor create
```

command which creates a new directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're just trying to create a new Meteor project, rename the original directory, run `meteor create`, merge the two directories, then run `git add .; git commit -a;`

If you want to pull Meteor from GitHub, just add it as a git submodule.

Comment: As mentioned below, `meteor create .` is the current way to go (running 1.2+)

Answer (score 39):

`$ meteor create .`

I started with a git repo that had a README.md file in there. The above command worked like a charm.

I'm running Meteor 1.2.0.2.

Comment: It was that simple all along? Nice one.

Comment: May not have been that easy for previous versions of Meteor.

Comment: This is now the most correct answer and should be marks as such. So clean!

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. e'rror: ENOTDIR, open '~/project/.meteor/.gitignore'

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current and somewhat nicer solution:

```
alias meteor-create='project_name=`basename ${PWD}` && meteor create ${project_name} && mv ${project_name}/{*,.*} ./ 2>/dev/null && rmdir ${project_name}'
```

This saves you a some of that work work. You can simple `cd` into the directory you where you want your project and do:

```
meteor-create
```

I'd also put the alias in by bashrc file:

```
cat <<'__' >> ~/.bashrc
alias meteor-create='project_name=`basename ${PWD}` && meteor create ${project_name} && mv ${project_name}/{*,.*} ./ 2>/dev/null && rmdir ${project_name}'
__
```